# Open-source/free alternative to Camtasia?

Tags: gratis, screen-recording

I am currently looking for software (for either Windows or OS X) that will be able to record the monitor playback and audio.

We would expect it to output into MP4 or some other current standard that is readable by HTML5.

We use Camtasia currently, but the licenses are expensive and we aren't really using it for more than the very basics.

Comment: Can you differentiate this question from other similar questions, or do the answers to other questions provide the recommendation(s) you seek?